# exception of duplicate key in my code

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview, textbox

I have a Form that contains an "Add" button and a textBox, which is used to add information to a database table.

I need to check if the code entered in the TextBox is available before I can insert it.

My problem is that I get errors, as it attempts to add a "duplicate primary key" and I'm unsure of the source of error.

Below is the code I currently have:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection1.Open();

    String reqt1="select numero_cpte from compte where numero_cpte="+textBox1.Text+";";

    SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand(reqt1, connection1);

    int d = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int dd = Convert.ToInt32(sql1.ExecuteScalar());

    if(d == dd) 
    { 
        int o1 = sql1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("this account is not valide!!","Fiche ");
        connection1.Close();
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You should insert the code!!","Fiche", 
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else 
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand sql = new 
                 SqlCommand("insert into compte values(" + textBox1.Text + ",'" +
                 textBox2.Text + "','" + type_cpteComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + 
                 "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() +
                 "'," + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + ",'" + 
                 checkBox1.Checked.ToString() + "','" + checkBox2.Checked.ToString() + 
                 "','" +textBox5.Text+ "','" +textBox6.Text+ "');", connection);

        int o = sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show(o + "Success of add","Fiche");

        connection.Close();

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
    }
```

This is the error I see:
[image]

The insert command works perfectly, but When I try to test if the code that I'am going to add in the base exists or not (by typing a code that I know exists), I get this exception.

Comment: Your code is written and formatted terribly. Building SQL commands using UI controls as direct input is a massive security problem. What if a user types in a SQL command segment in one of the textboxes? In addition, youre code is in French, making it hard to read for those who don't understand French. Please change it if you expect help.

Comment: ok xxbbcc I'am sorry I will translate it :)

Comment: Lina, translation is the smallest part of the problem - your sample shows multiple calls to SQL and there is no information about error which you claim comes from particular SQL call. Please remove all UI interaction from sample and use good variable names for public code. Add exact error text and point to line where exception is thrown. Make sure to add proper using to public version of code. (feel free to ignore above recommendation for version you use for yourself, but make sure to provide good looking code as public sample).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code drops down into the add code even if you have discovered that your number is a duplicate.  Try adding "return;" after you close the connection.

MessageBox.Show("Ce compte existe.Veuillez sasir un numéro de compte valide!!", "Fiche Comptes");
connection1.Close();
return;

Comment: Another suggestion...it is always a good idea to break out tasks that you find yourself repeating into well-named methods.  For example (see code below).  This will help you to see the flow of the code better.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private object ExecuteScalar(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection1.Open();
            SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection1);
            return sql1.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
```

The advantage of this is that you always know that your connection will be closed when you are done.  Even if you are only going to be calling this method once, it improves readability and is therefore helpful.